# public events in android

Tags: android, events, shared, public

What all system events are made public / shared and are accessible from within my android app ? e.g.

Events shared by other applications : new email received, calender meeting started etc,

Events shared by system : system going to be rebooted, a processes taking lot of CPU etc.

Can you point me any blogs/documentation in this regard ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about Intents.

You fire an Intent to another app to request it to do something for you

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

You can also listen for global events (text messages received, bluetooth turned on etc):

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers

Comment: but i dont see info about listening to specifically these global events text messages received, bluetooth turned on etc .. can u help me with the documentation for these pls ?

Comment: looks like action_state_changed is to be used for bluetooth state detection .. yet didn't find anything for sms received ..